# opencvsharp: The library is compiled without Qt support?

Tags: opencv, c#-4.0

i am using opencvsharp. I am making a program to capture webcam setream and add some text overlays. here is the code

```
using (CvCapture cap = CvCapture.FromCamera(0))

        using (CvWindow w = new CvWindow("OpenCV Example"))

        {

            while (CvWindow.WaitKey(10) < 0)

            {

                using (IplImage src = cap.QueryFrame())

                using (IplImage gray = new IplImage(src.Size, BitDepth.U8, 1))

                using (IplImage dstCanny = new IplImage(src.Size, BitDepth.U8, 1))

                {

                   src.CvtColor(gray, ColorConversion.BgrToGray);

                  Cv.Canny(gray, dstCanny, 50, 50, ApertureSize.Size3);
                  CvFont font = new CvFontQt("MS UI Gothic", 48, CvColor.Red, FontWeight.Bold, OpenCvSharp.FontStyle.Italic);
                  dstCanny.AddText("Hello Qt!!", new CvPoint(50, dstCanny.Height - 50), font);

                   w.Image = dstCanny;

                }

            }

        }
```

i am geetin following exception 
An unhandled exception of type `'OpenCvSharp.OpenCvSharpException'` occurred in OpenCvSharp.dll

Additional information: The library is compiled without Qt support

on this line

```
CvFont font = new CvFontQt("MS UI Gothic", 48, CvColor.Red, FontWeight.Bold, OpenCvSharp.FontStyle.Italic);
```

kindly help what me whats i am wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use "PutText" instead of "AddText" method.
For example:

```
dstCanny.PutText("Hello", new CvPoint(50, 50), new CvFont(FontFace.HersheyDuplex, 1, 1), CvColor.GreenYellow);
```